# can not connect with docker postgress sql container with psycopg2

Tags: python, docker, psycopg2

I am running a Postgres SQL database container with following command:

```
docker run  --name db -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -v pg
```

Of course I have changed the 'localhost' to 'db' since I am trying to connect with this container.
when I try to connect to the container database I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I cant use here Docker compose in this context ( I know how to run it though ).
What else I need to add in my docker command so that I can connect from python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course I have changed the 'localhost' to 'db' since I am trying to connect with this container.

No, you don't, your dockerfile is exposing the port 5432 to the host machine as stated by the flag `-p 5432:5432`

So if, you are trying to connect to the docker from your host machine, yoi will use the host `localhost`

I think you are confusing between docker and docker networking when we have multiple docker trying to communicate with each other as is the case is with docker-compose.

In case of docker-compose, when you have multiple services running, they can communicate with each other using the docker containers name as the host. Similar if you have a network between docker containers, they can communicate with each other using the docker name as the host

So if it was docker-compose, with the docker running on one container, and your app in another, in that case you would replace localhost with db.

Hope that clarifies things

Comment: Hello Hassan, Thank you for clearing this up. I appricate your input

Comment: Multiple containers being able to communicate with one another is not a docker-compose feature; it's a docker network feature.

Comment: I stand corrected, I will make the edit @AKX
Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

If your Python program is running on the Docker host, then you **don't** want to "of course" change `localhost` to `db` in your connection string, since (a) Docker doesn't change your host DNS settings (b) you're using `-p` to `p`ublish the service running on port 5432 to the host on port 5432.

You would only use the name `db` from another Docker container running in the same Docker network.